# calling a Javascript function that makes a click on a (hidden) button or link

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I call a javascript function that makes a click on a hidden commandButton but the click run when the page loads, not when I call the function.
this is the html code :

```
<p:inputText id="aa" value="#{bonBonneManagedBean.sel}" onkeyup="fnc()" />
<h:commandButton id="hh" onclick="#{bonBonneManagedBean.kk()}" style="display:none"/>
```

and the javaScript function :

```
function fnc()
{
    length = document.getElementById('form:aa').value.length;
    if(length == 10)
    {
        $("#hh").click();
        document.getElementById('form:aa').value = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the `action` attribute instead of `onclick` like this

```
<h:commandButton id="hh" action="#{bonBonneManagedBean.kk()}" style="display:none"/>
```

Note that you might have to add form prefix to the selector, like this

```
$("#myFormId\\:hh").click();
```

The same would work for a `commandLink` or any other 'clickable' component.

Comment: Also, maybe `hh` isn't the generated ID for the `<h:commandButton>`.

Answer (score 4):

Must there be a button on this page(which I doubt, seeing as you're hiding it anyways)? You're better served using something like `<p:remoteCommand/>` here

Ditch the hidden button and replace with

```
<p:remoteCommand name="fnc" actionListener="#{bonBonneManagedBean.kk}"/>
```

**But**, if it's an absolute requirement, you can very easily emulate a button click in js with the `click()` method from your function you need to

1. Change the `<h:commandButton/>` to a `<p:commandButton/>` so you can assign the button a `widgetVar` attribute(to guarantee the name of the element in the DOM). The `widgtetVar` attribute can be set on almost all primefaces components to make your life easier
2. Using the `widgetVar`, just call the `click()` method in your function

   ```
   <p:commandButton ajax="false" widgetVar="theButton" id="hh" action="#{bonBonneManagedBean.kk()}" style="display:none"/>
   <p:inputText id="aa" widgetVar="theTextBox" value="#{bonBonneManagedBean.sel}" onkeyup="fnc()" />
   ```

   and in the function:

   ```
    function fnc(){
        length = theTextBox.value.length;
        if(length == 10){
          theButton.click()
           theTextBox.value = "";
              }
            }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If the top answers from Daniel and Kolossus doesn't help out someone: I found that characters got put in front of the id I set in my case, therefore this helped me:

```
$('[id$=hh]').click();
```

Basically the selector is saying the id ends with 'hh' but may not be the full id.
This is also helpful in SF development as the same thing happens with comandButtons, etc.

Comment: please  learn about namingcontainers. Nothing is just put in front of it, they are the id's of the namingcontainers. Addressing components fully is better. Just make sure the namingcontainers have explicitly assigned id's