# How to refer to commandButton from javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I use a JSF 2.2, a Primefaces 6.0 and a CDI. One of my page includes a chart (Highcharts) and a simple form which interferes in my chart. I've cut my code to show you the most important part of my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">

<h:head> 
    <!-- loading css -->
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        //<![CDATA[

        $(function () {

            //some code

            //create the chart
            $('#container').highcharts({
                //some code
            }); 

            //JS action for button
            $('#filterForm\\:filterButton').click(function () {

                var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
                //setting different data for chart and redraw the chart
            });

        });

        //]]>
    </script>

    <div id="container" style="height: 750px; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;"/>

    <h:form id="filterForm">

        <p:selectManyCheckbox id="filter" value="#{visualizationController.selectedKindOfNetwork}" layout="responsive" columns="4">
            <p:ajax update="filterButton" listener="#{visualizationController.changeFiltrerForChart1a()}" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{visualizationController.kindOfNetwork}" var="kindOfNetwork" itemLabel="#{kindOfNetwork}" itemValue="#{kindOfNetwork}" />
        </p:selectManyCheckbox>

        <br/>

        <p:commandButton id="filterButton" value="Filtruj" action="#{visualizationController.actionFilterButtonForChart1a()}"
                        disabled="#{!visualizationController.visibilityFilterButtonForChart1a}"/>
    </h:form>

</h:body>         
</html>
```

I would like to achieve something like this:

- When I press a `commandButton` in my form, the code in below function should run:

  ```
  //JS action for button
  $('#filterForm\\:filterButton').click(function () {

      var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
      //setting different data for chart and redraw the chart
  });
  ```

**Do you have any idea how can I achieve that?**

At the moment, when I press the `commandButton`, the code in this function isn't run. In my opinion, the problem is in reference to the ID component: `#filterForm\\:filterButton` but maybe I'm wrong. When I wrote this reference, I based on [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813303/calling-a-javascript-function-that-makes-a-click-on-a-hidden-button-or-link) selected answer. There is a different problem than mine but there is a way to refer to the `<p:commandButton>` ID component so I thought that it'll be worked.

BTW: If I use a simple button (without the form) like in code snippet below, everything works, **but** I need the `<p:commandButton>` component.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    series: [{
      data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
  });


  // the button action
  $('#button').click(function() {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.series[0].setData([129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
<button id="button" class="autocompare">Set new data</button>
```

Comment: why not use the onstart or onclick attribute of the button? Why add this additional eventhandler?

Comment: I tried this as well. Instead of `$('#filterForm\\:filterButton').click(function () {//code});` I tried to create this: `function myFunction(){//code}` and then I called this function by means of a `onstart` attribute like this: `onstart="myFunction();"`. Unfortunately it isn't work (the code inside the function still doesn't run). Is it possible that the reason of this is fact that the `myFunction` is inside `$(function () {//here is myFunction});`?

Comment: Yes, myFunction must be outside $(function(){ ... });

Comment: look at the output generated from primefaces, it will hint you how to refer it in javascript

Comment: @Azazel, I did it before. @SiMag, thanks, so it works like I thought. Finally, I've moved some important variables outside and I've created two functions. One of them I use to create the chart and second of them I use to execute some code which is connected with the chart. I execute the second function using `oncomplete` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The solution

Finally, I've use `oncomplete` atrribute of the `<p:commandButton>` component instead of refer to the `<p:commandButton>` from the javascript code.

First of all, I've created two functions. One of them I use to create the chart. Second of them I use to execute some code which is connected with the chart. I've also moved and declared some important variables outside the functions. It allows me to refer to them inside the functions. Finally, I execute the second function by means of `oncomplete` attribute of the component.

Here is my modified code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">

<h:head> 
    <!-- loading css -->
</h:head>

<h:body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        //<![CDATA[

        //Declaration of variables
        var chart;

        //other variables...

        function firstFunction() {

            //Create the chart
            $('#container').highcharts({
                //some code
            }); 
        }

        function secondFunction() {

            chart = $('#container').highcharts();
            //Setting different data for chart and redraw the chart.
        }

        firstFunction();

        //]]>
    </script>

    <div id="container" style="height: 750px; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;"/>

    <h:form id="filterForm">

        <p:selectManyCheckbox id="filter" value="#{visualizationController.selectedKindOfNetwork}" layout="responsive" columns="4">
            <p:ajax update="filterButton" listener="#{visualizationController.changeFiltrerForChart1a()}" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{visualizationController.kindOfNetwork}" var="kindOfNetwork" itemLabel="#{kindOfNetwork}" itemValue="#{kindOfNetwork}" />
        </p:selectManyCheckbox>

        <br/>

        <p:commandButton id="filterButton" value="Filtruj" action="#{visualizationController.actionFilterButtonForChart1a()}"
                        disabled="#{!visualizationController.visibilityFilterButtonForChart1a}"
                        oncomplete="secondFunction();"/>
    </h:form>

</h:body>         
</html>
```